# How to use the MRTK Spectator View Feature?

Tags: mrtk

I wanted to check out the inner workings of the Spectator View feature, but I got stuck.
Checking out the Repo, Unity complains about missing the HololensForCV.dll. I didn't get very far.
I found the [Microsoft HoloLensForCV](https://github.com/microsoft/HoloLensForCV) repository, but could not compile it. I'm not even sure, if it did, that it will spit out the desired dll.

How do I get the branch to work?

Answer (score 1):

Update:

We have migrated to a new repository with samples and better documentation, please take a look here: https://github.com/microsoft/MixedReality-SpectatorView.

==================================================

Could you please try checking out this branch:
https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/tree/prerelease/2019.build.spectatorView

We have documentation for SpectatorView specifically here:
https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/blob/prerelease/2019.build.spectatorView/Assets/MixedRealityToolkit.Extensions/SpectatorView/SpectatorView.md

Please give it a try, and let me know if that helped.

Answer (score 0):

The feature/spectatorView branch in the Microsoft MixedRealityToolkit-Unity repo no longer has any scripts with dependencies on the dlls built out of HoloLensForCV. It may be worth checking your commit log to see if it matches with the current commit history for the feature/spectatorView.

FWIW, the main feature/spectatorView branch is undergoing a lot of refactoring/breaking changes. We forked the prerelease/2019.build.spectatorView branch so that folks could start looking at ASA localization for spectator view without having to be broken by rapid development underway in the feature branch. This prerelease only supports ASA localization for an android and HoloLens (1 or 2) device. ArUco marker and QR code based localization is in progress but not yet supported.