# Using MRTK with a Windows 10 tablet

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia, mrtk, windows-mixed-reality

I am trying to use a Windows 10 tablet for a Unity Mixed reality application. I am trying to create a Unity application where the tablet acts as a sort of window into the virtual world, overlaying virtual models on real world objects. The plan is to use vuforia for tracking and MRTK for camera tracking. I have been unable to take advantage of the tablet's gyro and accelerometer for the camera tracking. Is there any way to do this using the MRTK's camera rig?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Sorry for the down votes Mike, this is a valid question. It'd be great if the people who downvoted would tell you why. I can only guess it's because they know the answer already and assume it's obvious.

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't an immediately available tracking component for Unity/Windows 10 tablets similar to Android's ARCore or iOS's ARKit. You could theoretically use an open source SLAM algorithm project + the tablets RGB camera to try and piece together your own device tracking solution. This is beyond the scope of anything that the MRTK supports. Going down this path will likely prove non-trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the spectator view is something you gonna like. But its only compatible with `Android, iPhone` or a combination out of `HoloLens + Rig + Tripod + Video Camera + PC + Unity`.
You can read in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/spectator-view) about that or in this [so-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56584531/5818081).

Comment: MRTK is looking into supporting Android and iPhone as well in an upcoming release using Unity's ARFoundation package. Spectator View will be a good solution for viewing a HoloLens experience, MRTK's ARFoundation support may be a better solution for only building a single user experience on a mobile/tablet device.